# Empty values in manufacturer attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

Somehow there have been many (many!) thousands of empty values entered into my '**Manufacturer**' attribute. In the admin, if I go to `Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes` and try to load the manufacturer attribute, Chrome actually crashes after trying to load the page for several minutes. I got it to load once in Firefox, but there were too many empty records to delete manually.

If I `select * from eav_attribute_option_value` in mysql, I can't see any empty records at all...just valid records. So I'm really confused where these empty values are coming from.

Is there a table I am missing?